# How can I show single dialog box at directx?

Tags: directx, directx-9

I want to show dialog box at directx.
On full Screen, I can't see dialog box when I click button.
How can I show it when my project is full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem myself.
I typed this code.

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth            = m_config.nWidth;
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight           = m_config.nHeight;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat           = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
d3dpp.BackBufferCount            = 1;
d3dpp.MultiSampleType            = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;//D3DMULTISAMPLE_2_SAMPLES;
d3dpp.MultiSampleQuality         = 0;
d3dpp.SwapEffect                 = /*D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;//*/D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD; 
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow              = m_hWnd;
d3dpp.Windowed                   = true;
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil     = true;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat     = D3DFMT_D24S8;
d3dpp.Flags                      = D3DPRESENTFLAG_DISCARD_DEPTHSTENCIL|**D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER**;
d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;
d3dpp.PresentationInterval       = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
```

Then Create LPDirect3dDevice. After this,

m_pd3dDevice->SetDialogBoxMode(true);

Then the dialog box will show.